Polya urn scheme by induction task
I've been trying to solve the task given in "An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications" by William Feller. The task is to show by induction that the probability of a black ball in Polya urn scheme at any trial is b/(b+r), where b and r are the number of black and red before the first trial correspondingly.
(Polya's urn scheme) Initially, there are b+r balls in the urn. b denotes the number of black balls and r denotes the number of red balls. This implies that at the first stage, the probability to pick a black ball in the urn is bb+r. If the player picks a black ball at the previous stage, then c black balls are added to the urn. The case for red balls is the same, and this process is continued.

Suppose the assertion to be true for the nth drawing regardless of b, r and c. Considering the two possibilities at the first drawing we find then that the probability of black at the (n+1)st trial equals
$\frac{b}{b+r}\cdot\frac{b+c}{b+r+c} + \frac{r}{b+r}\cdot\frac{b}{b+r+c} 
=\frac{b}{b+r} $

Could you elaborate the solution from the book? It seems not explained completely.
As I understand, the first multipliers in each component of the sum are probabilities to draw black and red ball at the nth trial correspondingly. But what are the second multipliers? If it is a conditional probabilities, then how do we get them so?
original task from the book
original solution from the book

It's a simple decomposition. Let $p(b,r,n)$ be the probability of n^th ball being black given that there currently $b,r$ black and red balls in the urn. Then, the probability of the $n+1$ ball being black is the sum of:

the first ball being black and the nth ball afterward (which would be the n+1th) being black
the first ball being red and the nth ball afterward (which would be the n+1th) being black

That proves the inductive step.
I'll let you check the math.
